# Simple GridLayout scale animation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to scale X and Y of a GridLayout from 0 to 100. I want my grid to look "invisible" and than I want it to be very big by changing it's scale. However I get an exception every time I try to run my code:

```
   gameGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameView);
    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1,
                                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    gameGrid.setLayoutAnimation(new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation));
```

The object is not null, but I get this exception:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridLayout.setLayoutAnimation(android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController)' on a null object reference
```

How should I solve this? It's looks rather simple, what am I missing here please?

My XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">


  <GridLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:columnCount="7"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:rowCount="7"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:id="@+id/GameGrid">

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B1"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B2"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B3"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B4"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B5"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B6"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B7"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B8"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B9"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B10"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B11"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B12"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B13"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B14"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B15"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B16"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B17"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B18"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B19"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B20"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B21"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B22"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B23"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B24"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B25"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B26"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B27"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B28"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B29"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B30"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B31"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B32"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B33"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B34"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B35"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B36"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B37"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B38"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B39"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B40"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B41"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B42"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B43"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B44"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B45"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B46"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B47"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B48"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

      <com.tastudio.doors123.SquareButton
          android:id="@+id/B49"
          android:layout_margin="3dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/knight3" />

    </TableRow>
  </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml please?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the stack trace? I mean does the exception really occurs upon reaching the " gameGrid.setLayoutAnimation(new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation));" line?

Comment: First I find the element, later I try to animate it. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The object is not null, but I get this exception:

Your `GridView` id is :

```
android:id="@+id/GameGrid"
```

And you are doing this :

```
gameGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameView);
```

It should be this one

```
gameGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameGrid);
```

Also try to use `setAnimation()` instead of `setLayoutAnimation()` for me is working.

Comment: Thanks, but after the change I get this: "id.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController$AnimationParameters cannot be cast to android.view.animation.GridLayoutAnimationController$AnimationParameters"

Comment: Oh you changed it aswell, I was modifing my answer haha :D

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it like this:

```
   gameGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameGrid);
    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1,
                                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    gameGrid.setAnimation(animation);
    gameGrid.animate();
```